# Can you link adjectives in past tense?

Tags: adjectives

I know you can link adjectives in Japanese this way: using **-KUTE** for -I adjectives, and **DE** for -Na adjectives. For example:

Kirei(na) + Wakai + Yasashii + Onna --> "*Kirei**de**, waka**kute**, yasashii onna* (a beautiful, young and gentle woman)". きれいで、若くて、優しい女

I also know you can link adjectives in negative form this way: **-KUNAKUTE** for -I adjectives, **-DEHANAKUTE** / **-JANAKUTE** for -Na adjectives:

Kirei dehanai + Wakakunai + Yasashikunai + Onna --> "*Kirei dehana**kute**, wakakuna**kute**, yasashikunai onna* (a woman who is not beautiful, young or gentle)". きれいではなくて、若くなくて、優しくない女

But, the question is, can you apply this to link past form adjectives (*Kirei datta, Wakakatta, Yasashikatta...*)? Is this possible in Japanese? How would you say "*I miss a women that was beautiful and gentle*", or something like this.

Comment: 「きれいで優しかった女の人が恋しい」は、文法的には間違ってないと思いますが…その人は、今はきれいじゃないし優しくないんですか？

Answer (score 3):

When you want to simply join two adjectives using the te-form or the continuative form, conjugate the last adjective into the past tense, and that's enough.

- それは赤くて大きかった。
  それは赤く大きかった。
  It was red and big.
- それは大きくて赤かった。
  それは大きく赤かった。
  It was big and red.
- 彼は健康で美しかった。
  He was healthy and beautiful.
- 彼は美しくて健康だった。
  彼は美しく健康だった。
  He was beautiful and healthy.

This is the same as when you join two verbs to describe two past events (e.g., 朝食を食べて歯を磨いた).

In rare cases, you can use the ta-form like the following:

- 若かった美しい女性
  a beautiful woman who was (once) young
  <sub>(若かった is modifying the noun phrase 美しい女性)</sub>